# Why is there a Value property on the Option type in F#?

Tags: f#

According to the documentation for `Option.Value<'T>`:

> Get the value of a Some option. A NullReferenceException is raised if
>   the option is None.

and

> This function is for use by compiled F# code and should not be used
>   directly.

Does the last sentence imply that it's due to interop? What's the use case if so?
Otherwise it seems very strange since the whole point of the `Option` type is to make the possibility of undefined values explicit and encourage handling of them, which easily can be circumvented:

```
let none : int option = None
let value = none.Value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine it is there so that

```
match v with 
|Some(t) -> t
```

works - without that `Value` property, you wouldn't be able to get the `t` with any functions which are available to F# code (Note there are some DU properties which are not accesible from F# which are an alternative here).  There may also be some very minor speed benifits if you know that the option is `Some` as you don't check it if you use `value` directly

Comment: You are absolutely right, the code compiles to `return v.Value`.